# with the functions.php, my website get blank

Tags: php, function

i'm creating a theme and i had a problem with functions.php file
i used this code at firs

```
<?php 

 if(function_exists('register_sidebar')) 
 register_sidebar (array( 
 'name' =< 'follow us ', 
 'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">', 
 'after_widget' => '</div><!--End widget-cont--></div><!--End widget-->', 
 'before_title' => '<h2>', 
 'after_title' => '</h2><div class="widget-cont">', 
 )); 
 { 
 register_sidebar(); 
 } 
 ?>
```

and when i enter my website it get blank page and i get this

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in /home/u300164519/public_html/wp-content/themes/Abs Workout/functions.php on line 5

then i fixed the problem in line 5 and change it to this code

```
   <?php
 if(function_exists('register_sidebar'))
 register_sidebar (array( 
 'name' )< 'follow us ',
 'before_widget' )> '<div class="widget">' 
 'after_widget' => '</div><!--End widget-cont--></div><!--End widget-->',
 'before_title' => '<h2>',
 'after_title' => '</h2><div class="widget-cont">', 
  )); {
 register_sidebar(); 
 } 
 ?>
```

and again i get this!!!!

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/u300164519/public_html/wp-content/themes/Abs Workout/functions.php on line 7**

what dose that mean :(!
please helpp meeee!
**i'm tired of this :(**

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2chxQAkF

Comment: You should [learn the basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) first before posting debugging questions here.

Comment: The code is littered with syntax errors. Also (to @mr5 too), it should be `if (!function_exists` Redeclaring a function only if it already exists is a double mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

Try replacing `'name' )< 'follow us '`
With `'name' => 'follow us '`

and

`'before_widget' )> '<div class="widget">'`  with `'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">'`.

You need to have the array formatted this way:

```
array(
  key1 => value1,
  key2 => value2,
  keyN => valueN
);
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please don't forget to choose the answer as best answer if you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid  Its should be like

```
function my_side() {

 register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => 'box',
            'id' => 'box',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h3>',
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
        ) );

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_side' );
```